# Simulating varicap diode in LTSpice

Tags: diodes, simulation, ltspice, vco, varicap

I have been looking into making a voltage controlled oscillator using varicap diodes, however I have had hard time simulating the diodes in spice.

Would anyone here have an idea how this would be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Diode models have baseline capacitance and exponent used in the reverse-voltage effect on capacitance.

Comment: Have you tried searching the net for (your) models to see if they work?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can solve your problem by using variable capacitance models (intially found on the LTSpice Yahoo group I think ).
[image: spice_simulation_circuit]

The equation governing the charge and voltage of a capacitor is
\begin{equation}
Q = CV
\end{equation}
In LTSpice, you cannot change the capacitance value. Rather you specify the charge of the capacitor. Hence, you specify your capacitor value as:
\begin{equation}
q = V{(\text{your capacitance node})} \cdot x
\end{equation}
where x is the voltage over the capacitor in question. This is covered in the LTSpice Help file under *C. Capacitor*

Comment: I believe ocspro's solution does not respect conservation of charge. I advise reading this short article: https://designers-guide.org/modeling/varactors.pdf